# C# - Example of Extension Method

Tags: c#, linq, methods

Please could someone provide me with a simple extension method that for example squares a number.

I have drawn up so pseudo code:

```
class Program

int = x
---------------------

public static int square (this int x)

return x * square
```

Comment: Did you read the documentation?

Comment: I do not code in c#, and was wondering if anyone could help

Comment: I would normally paste http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx alone but noted that it said "Note that it is defined inside a non-nested, non-generic static class" instead of "Note that it **has to be** defined inside a non-nested, non-generic static class"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public static class NumberExtensions
{
  public static int Square(this int n)
  {
    return n*n;
  }
}
```

Now you can say:

```
int number=5.Square();
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is how you would write the method:

```
public static class ExtnMethods 
{
    public static int Square(this int x)
    {
        return x * x;
    }
}
```

Some important things to note about the above code:

- The class must be static and non-abstract
- The parameter `this int x` specifies that the method acts on an `int`

You would use it like so:

```
Console.WriteLine(5.Square());
// prints 25
```

Comment: I've edited your answer, you forgot to make Square method static! ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
public static class SomeClass { 
   public static int Square(this int x) {
      return x * x;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The extension method:

```
static class MathExtensions {

  public static Int32 Square(this Int32 x) {
    return x*x;
  }

}
```

How to use it:

```
var x = 5;
var xSquared = x.Square();
```

Comment: I've edited your answer too haha, both jjnguy and you forgot to make Square method static!! Ah, some suggestion, using CLR type names isn't recommended.

Answer (score -1):

In this example I tried to show you how use multiple Extension method in a single expression.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int x = 13;
        var ans = x.Cube().Half().Square();
        Console.WriteLine(ans);
    }
}

static class IntExtensions
{
    public static int Half(this int source)
    {
        return source / 2;
    }
    public static int Cube(this int source)
    {
        return (int)Math.Pow(source, 3);
    }
    public static int Square(this int source)
    {
        return (int)Math.Pow(source, 2);
    }
}
```